# Dataframe as a condition inside a dictionary, unhashable type?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have to create a python script from a VBA code with a big list condition. So I wanted to create two files. The first with the code, the second with a dict of conditions. I have information of a dataframe inside the dict and i got the error :

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'

The code :

```
df = pd.read_excel(xls, "Data")
from dictionnaire import big_one
conditions, valeurs = big_one(df2)
print(conditions)
```

(I added the dictionary below)

Is it possible to do something with my dataframe and a dictionary?
Since I have a lot of conditions and values and I have to modify them, I want to keep them together.

Thanks for your help !

Edit :

The VBA code look like this :

```
ElseIf ImpactedService = "A" Then DevServ = "Something"
ElseIf ImpactedService = "B" Then DevServ = "Something"
ElseIf ImpactedService = "C" Then DevServ = "Something"
ElseIf ImpactedService = "D" Then DevServ = "Something"
ElseIf ImpactedService = "E" Then DevServ = "Something"
ElseIf ImpactedService = "F" Then DevServ = "Something"
ElseIf ImpactedService = "G" Then DevServ = "Something"
ElseIf ImpactedService = "H" Then DevServ = "Something"
```

So my code is starting like this in the dictionary :

```
def big_one(df2):
    all_filters = {df2["A"].str.lower() : "something"}
    return all_filters.keys, all_filters.values
```

Comment: What does your list of conditions look like? Could you include some sample data?

Comment: It looks like you cannot use a pandas Series as a dictionnary key. You can invert the dict keys and values like `all_filters = {"something": df2["A"].str.lower()}` then access your filtered data with the key: `all_filters["something"]`. Also the function is returning keys and values separately, how are they used after?

Comment: It create a new column with the value. 
For example, if the column "A" has a specific value, then put "B" in the new column, for every row in a dataframe. A is a condition to create B in the new columns, i'm not sure to be clear, is it ok ? Also, i tried one more and that's working a bit more, i got no error but nothing in my variable now, it's better thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, the answer is to invert keys and values.
If you want to use np.select, the value must be equal to something.
It looks like this :

```
def big_one(df2):
    all_filters = {"A" : df2["B"].str.lower()=="C"}
    return all_filters.keys(), all_filters.values()
```

Thanks for your help !